# jetty-blazeds and maven (com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-core missing)

Tags: maven-2, jetty, blazeds

I want to setup jetty with jetty-blazeds extension. Everything looks fine but when I run maven to get the dependencies, I get:

```
UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES
com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-core;3.2.0: not found 
com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-common;3.2.0: not found
```

I've tried many repositories but no success. I am wondering has anyone managed to successfully locate these dependencies through maven ? If yes, could you please share the repository !

Thank you,
-A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the pom of jetty-blazeds, for example [jetty-blazeds-7.0.0.1beta3.pom](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-blazeds/7.0.0.1beta3/jetty-blazeds-7.0.0.1beta3.pom), you'll see this:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>project-repo</id>
      <name>project repo</name>
      <url>file:${basedir}/maven_repo</url>
      <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Jetty is using a file based repository. And if you look at this [file based repository](https://svn.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty/branches/jetty-7/jetty-blazeds/maven_repo/) in their svn repository, you will see that it contains the mentioned artifacts (which are thus very likely not available in any known public repository).

So my suggestion would be to use the same strategy i.e. to install the artifacts locally, either in your local repository or in a file based repository in your VCS (you could also declare https://svn.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty/branches/jetty-7/jetty-blazeds/maven_repo/ as repository but this is extremely ugly).

If you have a corporate repository, the alternative is obvious: deploy the adobe artifacts in it.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to set up a central Maven repository for your project/department and configure it in the project pom. Then you can download such dependencies by hand and deploy them manually to the project repo. Although this is a bit more extra work, it eliminates the whole class of problems in the long run.

Comment: Sure, that's one option to solve this. Since my project is a simple one, I would rather use some existing repositories (If I can find the one which contains the aforementioned flex artifacts).

Comment: @Ali In case of a one man project, you could even copy the needed dependencies into the local repo on your own machine - I don't think it could get any simpler than that. OTOH this makes your project unportable... simplicity has its price :-)